# Serialize to specific binary encoding

Tags: encoding, binary, buffer, rust

I'm writing a Rust wrapper for a binary protocol (Netlink) and for that purpose I need to encode some data (Strings and different sorts of ints and uints) into some kind of buffer, and I saw that `Vec<u8>` is uausally used for that. My current pseudocode looks like this:

```rust
struct NetlinkHeader {
    length: u32,
    _type: u16,
    flags: u16,
    sequence: u32,
    pid: u32
}

impl NetlinkSerializable for NetlinkHeader {
    fn to_wire_format(&self) -> Result<str, &'static str> {
        let mut binary_data: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(16);
        binary_data.add_binary_representation(self.length);
        binary_data.add_binary_representation(self._type);
        binary_data.add_binary_representation(self.flags);
        binary_data.add_binary_representation(self.sequence);
        binary_data.add_binary_representation(self.pid);
    }
}
```

I need help implementing something that does what `add_binary_representation` in the above pseudocode would do.

Comment: I think it would be best if you made a topic for each specific problem you're encountering rather than asking how to write such a lib in general. If you don't even know where to start I suggest looking at the rustc_serialize crate.

Comment: @A.B. Is it specific enough now?

Comment: IIRC this was moved out of the standard library and can be found in a crate. https://crates.io/crates/byteorder. https://crates.io/crates/podio.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I overload the argument type of the method `add_binary_representation`?" or are you asking "how do I write specific bytes or bits to a vector"?

Comment: The question is more about how to write the different data types to vectors. The libraries ArtemGr linked seem to help, I'll see if I need anything else.